# How to apply string comparisons between whole columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, text

I got a dataframe in this form

```
data = {'id':['1','2','3','4'], 'activity': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'], 'value': ['c',np.nan,np.nan,"a",]}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and want to extract the id's of the rows where the strings of the value/string column are contained in the activity column (also string) and write them in a new column next to (index) the values.

This is what I tried but i don't know how to apply the str.contains function between the two columns.

```
data['Mapping'] = data.id[data['activity'].str.contains([data.value],na=False)]
```

My expected outcome would be:

```
data = {'id':['1','2','3','4'], 'activity': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'], 'value': ['c',np.nan,np.nan,"a",], 'Mapping':['3',np.nan,np.nan,'1']}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
df['Mapping'] = df['value'].map(dict(zip(df.activity.str.extract(pat = f"({'|'.join(df.value.dropna())})")[0], df['id']))).where(df['value'].notna())
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
  id activity value Mapping
0  1      aaa     c       3
1  2      bbb   NaN     NaN
2  3      ccc   NaN     NaN
3  4      ddd     a       1
```